# Setup a RasPi for remote access before moving it to another network

Tags: remote

I am planning on getting a RasPi & configure it for remote access. The only issue is that it will be moved to another network overseas (I will send it with someone to connect it to the LAN). I will keep referring to this network as the LAN (see below).

So my questions is whether and how could I do this especially after reading this line from [this reply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/44535/46850).

> you need to know the external IP and of the Pi and setup port-forwarding through the network router in your lab.

One idea I got is to have a script which collects the needed information (not sure if that's possible) once or after it is connected to the modem & share the file through some service (e.g. Dropbox) I setup to have access to before sending it.

If all is needed is the IP address that would be easy to acquire with this idea. But I am not sure If I need access to the modem and port forwarding. Is the IP enough to connect to it?

PS 1: the LAN it will be connected to is mine but I am overseas.
PS 2: the modem for that LAN has OpenDNS installed on it, if relevant.

Comment: I would consider connecting to the Pi using a USB -> UART serial connection.  From there you will be able to Putty or other serial terminal into the Pi and setup its network connections.  Then when you reboot it, it will be able to connect to the LAN as desired.

Comment: There are three issues: (1) how does the RPi get an address, (2) how do you learn that address, (3) do you have connectivity to that address (through firewalls, NAT, etc)? Some answers might be (1) DHCP, (2) a post-up script to wget http://my.web.server/, (3) ask the host network nicely. A common approach in this situation is to run a OpenVPN tunnel over HTTPS back to a server you control: then you don't need local help for (3) and it also solves (2) and you use DHCP for (1).

Comment: @Kolban I don't understand to what it would be connected to?

Comment: @vk5tu Would it be possible to do this through a script which shares the data once connected ? (updated the question with the idea)